# How does BIOS know which disk's MBR should it use?

Tags: boot, bios, mbr

Generally, BIOS will read the MBR in disk, but if there are multiple disks, how will the bios determine which disk's MBR should be read?

Comment: There's also such magic as BIOS settings for boot order.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about UNIX or Linux. It should have been asked on Super User instead.

Answer (score 1):

Bios loads mediums in some strict order that is present in its settings. Therefore, if you have disk A and B plugged in, then MBR of the disk that will be loaded first is used. You can always change this option in BIOS settings.

More generally, BIOS is aware that there are multiple media it can boot into, but it doesn't check them all(is unaware of their partitioning schemes); it loads the first one, and uses its MBR. Other disks don't even have to have MBR.

Same applies to GPT.